# Awesome - swapping windows

Tags: linux, awesome-wm

I was wondering if there's a shortcut to swap windows. Say a have two horizontal windows, and I want the upper one to go down and viceversa. I checked the manual with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Mod4 + Shift + j` or `Mod4 + Shift + k`.

From the manual:

> Layout modification
>
> > Mod4 + Shift + j
> >
> > > ```
> > >    Switch client with next client.
> > > ```
> >
> > Mod4 + Shift + k
> >
> > > ```
> > >    Switch client with previous client.
> > > ```

Comment: thanks, it wasn't working to me because I had all windows maximized